# Use string to access properties of a readonly object in typescript

Tags: typescript, object-literal

```
const parent2 = {child: 'name'}
const index2: string = 'child';
const child3 = parent2[index2]
```

When I try to access `child` in `parent2` I get the following error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ child: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ child: string; }'
```

Is there an easy way to make `parent2[index2]` return `'name' | undefined` ?

It's even more difficult to deal with nested readonly object. `allowStringIndex` type keeps index autocomplete and it allows accesing properties using string, but it's annoying to construct the type. Is there an easy way to access `nestedObject[grandParentIndex]?.[parentIndex]`

```
const nestedObject = {grandParent: {name: 'grandparent', parent: {name: 'parent', child: {name: 'child'}}}} as const;
type child = {name: 'child', [key: string]: 'child' | undefined}
type parent = {name: 'parent', child: child}
type overrideParent = parent & {[key: string]: parent[keyof parent] | undefined}
type grandParent = {name: 'grandparent', parent: overrideParent}
type overrideGrandParent= grandParent & {[key: string]: grandParent[keyof grandParent] | undefined}

type allowStringIndex = {grandParent: overrideGrandParent} & {[key: string]: overrideGrandParent | undefined}

const castedObject = nestedObject as allowStringIndex;
const grandParentIndex: string = 'grandparent';
const parentIndex: string = 'parent'

const child = nestedObject[grandParentIndex]?.[parentIndex]?.['child']
const parent1 = castedObject[grandParentIndex]?.[parentIndex]
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=31&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCm14BMDyAjAVvYsC8MA3gOYBOAhmMgArmnxhQBcRY5AtvCwORmXIAHOgyjcANDCH1GLQm048pI8TGAALAJYAbZLPlcY3dduTcAvhbMxyEVeGgBuAFBQAngPirNOmATkcDI29TCQBtAGt4VxZoUg0wYgBdHmMdbhgAHxgAVyp4ADN4lDMXd08lRl9WAMVhRhVU3S8TErcPGBAAN3hSOOR4Wml8STrYADIiCKiYqDiE5JGhqdcQfMWRRMycvMKEZFaymD4qQZEq-wVDY8FRlQrmDu7ejX7TxgP2rp6++ABxChOowI1ze40mkWiMFi8SSLBBo2WqyOAJoo02WVy-V2xScpXa5C0WhAAHcAMqzGEASTyAA9zvChiwvs9+v9+KCrBNCMsZnNYY9vi8-ijQVtMQUivtcaBILBgDYoCgMNhcFUEEg0FgcLAbNZCSTyXzqf0ac4ZdBkezRsb4DTeTCqrwUfduGb7LB7ja7VCKQlHS7pe7mj4COrFZqVVBQgyRF7EgB+AB0oU9tITyaCJm4iSc5o9owAjFV5RrldroyLrWmkymqyac7mg-cAEznRo8fTmRuymDxE3N+1+giZtJunuNADMVRboT7tubDaAA

Recursive type doesn't work perfectly
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCm14BMDyAjAVvYsC8MA3gOYBOAhmMgArmnxhQBcRY5AtvCwORmXIAHOgyjcANDCH1GLQm048pI8TGAALAJYAbZLPlcY3dduTcAvhbMxyEVeGgBuAFAuoATwHwYAQS1aQAO4AylCkGmDEAJJU8AAeADwAsuQCnmhYOLBxUAzItkEArqkgpDnp2LgSAGrkWgXwACoeXgTQYREwAD5wBezo8KQShcWlKBgV+NZgbgB8MHhOMDDJqWMZuDDZubaEMADaANbwbjDhMEduIABmyylp45kAuiw1dY3NMFYA-ItLRPsXU5gc7Ha63VblJ4sFb3dZQQ7HR6fGAAMn+CLcLDa4WIz3BsImGLBMLWEyR3QKMSu4RQn1+S1kAOOQJBlxuJMhuDxvn8wVCOOiyDiSTupMyGMecysaN2GKx-Ii3L8gRC7SiMQSHIeuCJ7NFnKgkq6MEpQupCGQdJcoEgsGANjK2smCCQBusth5KoV6qFCXcnjBLsdcJmzicNugkmEjH081UDrFuAAdHwqLRpFAk0pGEn9OH7LBUzRo1BBXF5Wq47wKFRs6J87aoxmy7EKziq3XuA3I3WAIxx+2up17IvpkQtx5fJN7OsTlxOIA

Answer (score 0):

Why are you explicitly typing your string consts with `: string` instead of letting TypeScript infer the value? [You can just remove those](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCm14BMDyAjAVvYsC8MA3gOYBOAhmMgArmnxhQBcRY5AtvCwORmXIAHOgyjcANDCH1GLQm048pI8TGAALAJYAbZLPlcY3dduTcAvhbMxyEVeGgBuAFBQAngPirNOmATkcDI29TCQBtAGt4VxZoUg0wYgBdHmMdbhgAHxgAVyp4ADN4lDMXd08lRl9WAMVhRhVU3S8TErcPGBAAN3hSOOR4Wml8STrYADIiCKiYqDiE5JGhqdcQfMWRRMycvMKEZFaymD4qQZEq-wVDY8FRlQrmDu7ejX7TxgP2rp6%20%20ABxChOowI1ze40mkWiMFi8SSLBBo2WqyOAJoo02WVy-V2xScpXa5C0WhAAHcAMqzGEASTyAA9zvChiwvs9%20v9%20KCrBNCMsZnNYY9vi8-ijQVtMQUivtcaBILBgDYoCgMNhcFUEEg0FgcLAbNZCSTyXzqf0ac4ZdBkezRsb4HSCLwRbczfZYPcbXbDPduNKXc0fAR1YrNSqoKEGSJ3YkAPwAOlCbtp0bjQRM3ESTnNrtGAEYqvKNcrtWHHUNI7H49bEz7ZetGAAmc6NHj6cwZ33xE0N%202NbjOmuNADMVXuddCHdtdfTQA). Also, you seem to have misspelled the string assigned to `grandParentIndex`, it should be `"grandParent"` not `"grandparent"`?

```
// Don't do this
const parentIndex: string = 'parent'

// Do this
const parentIndex = 'parent';
```

Comment: People pass those string literals as strings instead of generic in function arguments. Sometimes those string literals are from angular router which is not typed